# Bash not working in vscode terminal and an alert I can't figure out

Tags: environment-variables, alert, git-bash

I moved vscode to a different place. Then it all started happening.

[the snippet of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27OH4.png)

I can't see the option of git-bash in terminal.
I tried reinstalling.

[alert on top of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF9PA.png)

The alert is scary and it shows up everytime I open vs code.

Git is working fine (Checked the version in git-bash).

Changed *settings.json* by adding environment path of ..bin\bash.exe.
I don't know where I'm going wrong.

I want to set bash as default. And it should be able to run all the commands and load all packages like it did earlier.

Also, I don't want something to be deleted at an uncertain time (that alert).
Please help!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have opened VS Code in it's installation folder, you would get the alert (based on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/138815). As the issue mentions, placing your files in the installation folder is not a good idea. As for `bash`, can you try adding the full path to `git-bash` exe in the settings.json ?

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the alert thing. Bash just won't work. What's the solution? If you could dig deeper. It is showing the git version in powershell though. So I think no problem with git.

Comment: I'm not on Windows right now, so can't confirm what would be the right value. But some quick Googling has led me to this: https://neutrondev.com/vs-code-integrate-git-bash-default-terminal/. I'm assuming you are trying the "Third way" here ? Just make sure the backslashes are right and that you have given the full path from C:\ or D:\. Also, the first 2 ways would probably be better, if you haven't already tried them.

Comment: I honestly can't thank you enough. Thank you so much @DevanshSharma. Best day today lol. Thank you!